# Deleting node in C BST

Tags: c

I have a problem with deleting node when I have two children, i don't have any idea what to do, cuz I have solved problem with no children, left child and right child

```
struct Node* deleteNode(Node *root, int val)
    {
        if(root == NULL) return root;
        else if(val < root->data) 
            root->left = deleteNode(root->left,val);
        else if(val > root->data) 
            root->right = deleteNode(root->right, val);
        else 
        {
            if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            {
                free(root);
                root = NULL;
            } 
            else if(root->left == NULL)
            {
                Node *temp = root;
                root = root->right;
                free(temp);
            } 
            else if(root->right == NULL)
            {
                Node *temp = root;
                root = root->left;
                free(temp);
            } 
    }
```

Comment: `struct Node* deleteNode(Node *root, int val)`  => `struct Node* deleteNode( struct Node *root, int val)`  Did this code compile?

Comment: it was `node* deleteNode(node *tree, int val)` sorry

Comment: Note that most paths out of this function do not return a value.  That is not going to make for happiness.  Your compiler should be warning you about that.  If it isn't, it's time to turn on more compilation warnings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So what should I do to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you must make one sub-node a child of the other. You'll have to do another recursive function for the add, in case neither sub node has degree < 1

Comment: Yep, but i don't know how to do it at all... On Internet i have only searched deleting with function "findMin", but I don't understand that way.